# Hyperbolic substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I’m studying hyperbolic substitutions, in particular:
$$ \int \sqrt{x^2-1} dx $$
Where I should substitute $x=cosh(t)$.But cosh codomain is $[1,+ \infty[$, while $x$ can also be smaller than $-1$, so in my opinion ,we can’t do this substitution. Can you help me?

Comment: The integrand is not defined whenever |x|<1. Moreover, $$\int_{|x|>1}\sqrt{x^2-1}dx=2\int_1^\infty \sqrt{x^2-1}dx.$$

Comment: You can use $x=\cosh(t)$ as well ! And for an even integrand, this does not matter.

Comment: @YvesDaoust now that all of you make me notice this, it's pretty obvious that I could have just splitted the two cases and then "glue them together". In my class it wasn't so obvious.

Comment: @Eureka: oops, the minus sign has disappeared from my comment. $-\cosh(t)$ intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the functions $f:(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ such that $f'(x)=\sqrt{x^2-1}$, then what you do is notice that by mean value theorem those functions are exactly the ones such that there are some $c,d\in\Bbb R$ such that $$f(x)=\begin{cases}c+\int_{-1}^x \sqrt{t^2-1}\,dt&\text{if }x\le-1\\ d+\int_1^x\sqrt{t^2-1}\,dt&\text{if }x\ge1\end{cases}$$

And then work on $\left.f\right\rvert_{[1,\infty)}$ and $\left.f\right\rvert_{(-\infty,-1]}$ separately. For the integral which appears for $\left.f\right\rvert_{(-\infty,-1]}$ you can make the substitution $t=-\cosh s$.

Comment: thank you so much :) . I would have really appreciated this formalism in my class.